# Struts - Environment-based config

Tags: maven, ant, struts

I'm trying to sort out a rather old system that has a couple of webapps using Struts. The previous build system has just been a suite of rather hacky Ant scripts that have built up over the years, which I'm attempting to replace with Maven and a proper CI (Jenkins).

The issue I have at the moment is that there is an Ant task called 'build-live' that replaces the strings '8080' and '4343' (dev values) with '80' and '443' (live values) respectively, in the struts-config.xml files of a couple of the webapps. There is a task 'build-local' that does the opposite.

The XML in the config file is as follows:

```
<plug-in className="org.apache.struts.action.SecurePlugIn">
    <!-- Set to 80 by 'build-live' Ant task -->
    <set-property property="httpPort" value="8080"/>
    <!-- Set to 443 by 'build-live' Ant task -->
    <set-property property="httpsPort" value="4343"/>
</plug-in>
```

I've managed to use the AntRun plugin in Maven to do the same, so it can work with Maven, but because this requires a rebuild dependent on environment, it breaks my main goal of 'Build Once, Deploy Anywhere'.

Therefore, I was hoping someone could explain to me if it's possible to turn these into properties that can be injected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up extending the SecurePlugIn class with my own, and overriding the init method:

```
public class PropertisedSecurePlugin extends SecurePlugIn {

    @Override
    public void init(ActionServlet servlet, ModuleConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(servlet, config);
        String dev = System.getProperty("dev");
        if (Boolean.TRUE.toString().equals(dev)) {
            setHttpPort("8080");
            setHttpsPort("4343");
        } // Else not required here as it falls back to defaults
    }
}
```

It's dirty, but it works.